# How to convert smart card APDU command on java to c#?

Tags: java, c#, smartcard

I have Java code that works fine for reading data from an smart card:

```
byte[] dataSetEF12 = {0, -80, -110, 0, 0};
apdu = new CommandAPDU(dataSetEF12);
ResponseAPDU response = cardChannel.transmit(apdu);
byte[] data = response.getData();
```

But I need this on c# & I write this:

```
apdu = new APDUCommand(0x00, 0xB0, 0x92, 0x00, null, 0x00);
APDUResponse response = cardReader.Transmit(command);
byte[] data = response.Data;
```

But on c# response.Data equals to null

Anyone know what is my mistake
or what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what status code which is returned from card, your problem maybe has several reasons:

1. SW = 61XX; You have to send GET_RESPONSE command to card.
2. SW = 9000; You have to Check you C# wrapper. (Maybe you have to set Le in command apdu)
3. SW = 6F00; Some thing wrong in your command or card
4. SW = anything else; You have to search it on the web.

Good luck

Comment: I guess, the final 00 is already the LE; but I know that Java computes LC by itself, which might need to be manually done  from another language.